# I have downloaded a script from my friend over the internet, (tampermonkey) will he be able to update the script without me knowing?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

Basically, it is a script on a betting site and the site has a function to send money to friends, it is possible to make a script designed to steal money, the script he has sent does not include this line of code, however I am worried that he may be able to update the script without me knowing to add this line which would steal my money, so my question is..... is it possible to update a script if you are the original maker of said script through tamper monkey? Sorry if I am unclear I am trying my best here ;D

Answer (score -1):

No it's not possible since he to change the script needs to modify it from your computer. If i give you a script and you upload it but then I change it you'll have the code for the first version not the second one so if i want to have the new version on your computer i have to be there to upload it.

Comment: Thank you! just wanted to make sure as I have never used Tamper Monkey before!

Comment: This is not true.  The default is that Tampermonkey will check for updates depending on the `@updateURL` setting (and/or other factors).  It is very possible that the script can update without the OP noticing it.

Comment: He can remove that and not get the updates. Problem. Even if he forgets the **@updateurl** he needs to add it at his place. And also we don't know how he's script looks.